# Not able share a video link created by the Open graph protocol in the facebook

Tags: facebook

I have create a video link using Open Graph protocol. After clicking on like button that link comes on my wall post. Now I am going to share it but it's not sharing.

My code for generate video link something like this

`

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html >
<title>Facebook Like Demo</title>
<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# video: http://ogp.me/ns/video#">
    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="xxxxxxxxxxx" />
    <meta property="og:title" content="title.." />
    <meta property="og:description" content=" some description..." />
    <meta property="og:type" content="video" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="image url" />
    <meta property="og:video" content="video url" />
    <meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash" />
    <meta property="og:video:width" content="400" />
    <meta property="og:video:height" content="300" />
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="test_app" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="fb-root">
    </div>

    <script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=xxxxx";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

    <fb:like href="link url" send="true" width="450"
        show_faces="true">
    </fb:like>
</body>
</html>
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a feeling that the URL is not being seen correctly by Facebook's servers when they call out to it.  Run your URL thru the linter tool and fix any warnings and errors it tells you about.  The linter is:  https://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint